# what does this vimrc line do exactly

Tags: search, macros, vim

How does this line work:

```
nnoremap <leader>ws mz:%s/\s\+$//<cr>:let @/=''<cr>
```

I know it does a no recursion map to `<leader>ws`  and I know it uses a macro and does a search and replace, but I cant follow it exactly. Please help me wrap my head around this! I don't want to add things I cant understand to my vimrc

I also know that it sets a mark z then starts the global search and replace.  but it does n't seem to make use of that mark...

Ive come to the conclusion that the mark was forgotten and that it should have been appended to the end to return to the line where ww was called. I added that now. But still dont follow the rest.